# C++20 Multi-queue Thread Pool with Work Stealing

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrency, c++20

This is a follow up to my [previous post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/274415/c20-single-queue-thread-pool) which also follows up on my [first post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/270236/c20-thread-pool) regarding my thread pool implementation. I have since made some further changes and attempted to improve performance with work stealing.

The most up to date version of the code is available on my [Github](https://github.com/DeveloperPaul123/thread-pool).

Previously, I removed the use of multiple queues and went with a single queue in conjunction with a `std::condition_variable` but have now moved back to using multiple queues combined with a `std::binary_semaphore` as the signal for the thread to do work. I've also attempted to implement a basic work stealing strategy and it seems to have improved the base performance of the thread pool compared to a using a single queue without work stealing.

I think the next logical improvement to make would be to use a lock free queue but I still need to do some testing to see if the performance gain would be worth it.

Something I wasn't able to solve is allowing users to pass a refernece to a lambda function that is given to the thread pool. For example, the following code would not work. `x` would never be modified.

```
int x = 2;
pool.enqueue_detach([](int &value) { value = 4; }, std::ref(x));
```

`thread_pool.h`

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <atomic>
#include <concepts>
#include <deque>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <memory>
#include <semaphore>
#include <thread>
#include <type_traits>

#include "thread_pool/thread_safe_queue.h"

namespace dp {

    template <typename FunctionType = std::function<void()>>
    requires std::invocable<FunctionType> &&
        std::is_same_v<void, std::invoke_result_t<FunctionType>>
    class thread_pool {
      public:
        explicit thread_pool(
            const unsigned int &number_of_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency())
            : tasks_(number_of_threads) {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < number_of_threads; ++i) {
                threads_.emplace_back([&, id = i](const std::stop_token &stop_tok) {
                    do {
                        // wait until signaled
                        tasks_[id].signal.acquire();

                        do {
                            // invoke the task
                            while (auto task = tasks_[id].tasks.pop()) {
                                try {
                                    pending_tasks_.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release);
                                    std::invoke(std::move(task.value()));
                                } catch (...) {
                                }
                            }

                            // try to steal a task
                            for (std::size_t j = 1; j < tasks_.size(); ++j) {
                                const std::size_t index = (id + j) % tasks_.size();
                                if (auto task = tasks_[index].tasks.steal()) {
                                    pending_tasks_.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release);
                                    std::invoke(std::move(task.value()));
                                }
                            }

                        } while (pending_tasks_.load(std::memory_order_acquire) > 0);
                    } while (!stop_tok.stop_requested());
                });
            }
        }

        ~thread_pool() {
            // stop all threads
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < threads_.size(); ++i) {
                threads_[i].request_stop();
                tasks_[i].signal.release();
                threads_[i].join();
            }
        }

        /// thread pool is non-copyable
        thread_pool(const thread_pool &) = delete;
        thread_pool &operator=(const thread_pool &) = delete;

        template <typename Function, typename... Args,
                  typename ReturnType = std::invoke_result_t<Function &&, Args &&...>>
        requires std::invocable<Function, Args...>
        [[nodiscard]] std::future<ReturnType> enqueue(Function f, Args... args) {
            auto shared_promise = std::make_shared<std::promise<ReturnType>>();
            auto task = [func = std::move(f), ... largs = std::move(args),
                         promise = shared_promise]() {
                try {
                    promise->set_value(func(largs...));
                } catch (...) {
                    promise->set_exception(std::current_exception());
                }
            };

            // get the future before enqueuing the task
            auto future = shared_promise->get_future();
            // enqueue the task
            enqueue_task(std::move(task));
            return future;
        }

        template <typename Function, typename... Args>
        requires std::invocable<Function, Args...> &&
            std::is_same_v<void, std::invoke_result_t<Function &&, Args &&...>>
        void enqueue_detach(Function &&func, Args &&...args) {
            enqueue_task(
                std::move([f = std::forward<Function>(func),
                           ... largs = std::forward<Args>(args)]() mutable -> decltype(auto) {
                    // suppress exceptions
                    try {
                        std::invoke(f, largs...);
                    } catch (...) {
                    }
                }));
        }

      private:
        template <typename Function>
        void enqueue_task(Function &&f) {
            const std::size_t i = count_++ % tasks_.size();
            pending_tasks_.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
            tasks_[i].tasks.push(std::forward<Function>(f));
            tasks_[i].signal.release();
        }

        struct task_item {
            dp::thread_safe_queue<FunctionType> tasks{};
            std::binary_semaphore signal{0};
        };

        std::vector<std::jthread> threads_;
        std::deque<task_item> tasks_;
        std::size_t count_{};
        std::atomic_int_fast64_t pending_tasks_{};
    };

}  // namespace dp
```

And for clarity, my thread safe queue implementation:

`thread_safe_queue.h`

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <deque>
#include <mutex>
#include <optional>

namespace dp {
    template <typename T>
    class thread_safe_queue {
      public:
        using value_type = T;
        using size_type = typename std::deque<T>::size_type;

        thread_safe_queue() = default;

        void push(T&& value) {
            std::lock_guard lock(mutex_);
            data_.push_back(std::forward<T>(value));
        }

        [[nodiscard]] bool empty() const {
            std::lock_guard lock(mutex_);
            return data_.empty();
        }

        [[nodiscard]] std::optional<T> pop() {
            std::lock_guard lock(mutex_);
            if (data_.empty()) return std::nullopt;

            auto front = data_.front();
            data_.pop_front();
            return front;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] std::optional<T> steal() {
            std::lock_guard lock(mutex_);
            if (data_.empty()) return std::nullopt;

            auto back = data_.back();
            data_.pop_back();
            return back;
        }

      private:
        using mutex_type = std::mutex;
        std::deque<T> data_{};
        mutable mutex_type mutex_{};
    };
}  // namespace dp
```

Any and all feedback is much appreciated. Would you use this in one of your projects? Why or why not? My goal is to have something that is performant but also reasonably robust for the majority of use cases. Working on this project has been a great learning experience in the context of concurrent programing. It is a very interesting, albeit deceptively difficult, field.

Answer (score 2):

## Create a `struct worker`

You have a the member variables `threads_` and `tasks`, one is a `std::vector` and the other a `std::deque`. But the threads and task queues should always come in pairs, so it makes sense to group them in a `struct worker`, and then have a `std::vector<worker> workers_`:

```
class thread_pool {
    ...
    struct worker {
         task_item tasks_;
         std::jthread thread_;
    };
    ...
    std::deque<worker> workers_;
};
```

## Consider an exception being thrown in the constructor

If an exception is thrown in the constructor, for example if creating a new thread fails, then all objects constructed so far will be destructed. The user-defined destructor of `thread_pool` itself will not be called though. This is a problem, because the threads that have been spawned so far are all waiting on `tasks_[id].signal.acquire()`. The destructor of `std::jthread()` runs, but signalling the stop token doesn't cause the `std::binary_semaphore` to be released, so when it tries to join the worker thread the main thread will also wait forever.

The solution is to catch exceptions and ensure the threads are shut down correctly in the `catch` statement. Also be aware that in this case, the first thing each thread will do is try to steal work from another thread. So you also have to be sure that all of `tasks_` has been initialized before any thread starts, or reorder the code somehow to ensure it first checks the stop token before trying to do or steal work.

## Workers are too eager to steal?

Stealing work is slower than doing your own work. Whenever a worker's own task queue is empty, it will visit every other worker, and try to steal one task from each of them. You might want to add a `break` statement so it goes back to its own queue after it has stolen a task.

## `steal()` is functionally equivalent to `pop()`

There is no reason for `steal()` to pop from the back instead of the front, so you could just as well call `pop()`.

## Move objects where possible

In `pop()` and `steal()`, you are making a copy of the front or back element, then erasing the original. If `T` has a move constructor it would be nicer to move the element, so just write something like `auto front = std::move(data_.front())`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Regarding exceptions being thrown in the constructor: If I am catching the exception, do I need to shut down the already created threads in the catch block? Couldn't I just let the thread pool operate with as many threads as it can create? It should operate as normal right just with fewer threads?

Comment: Sure, if it is not an issue that you run with fewer worker threads than planned, then you can indeed just continue. Of course you should make the constructor itself throw an exception if no threads could be created at all.